# iPhone : Device Token Inactive in Urban Airship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, urbanairship.com

I am getting following error message on Urban Airship.

```
     Apple Push service rejected device token 38A69702F555A3B17F73FB4DB835C0E5 AD31ED987030202AADF45C5170C9EFDC.
     Original Message: {"aps":{"sound":"cat.caf","badge":4,"alert":"This is Test Message."}}
```

And It is showing Status as `INACTIVE` for this particular Device Token.

What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most common occurrence for rejected device tokens is sending a development device token to an ad-hoc/production app setup, or vice-versa.